# How to plot gradient boosting regression predictions

Tags: python, plot, regression, prediction, gradient-descent

I'm using GradientBoostingRegressor and I'm trying to plot my regression line. 
I believe the plotted regression line should look similar to the red line here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_quantile.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-quantile-py

I've come up with the following code however it doesn't quite meet my needs.  I feel like staged_predict() may help but haven't quite figured it out.

```py
# Gradient Boosting - fit the model
gbm = GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=360, learning_rate=0.06)
gbm.fit(train_data, train_values_log)
predict_dev_log = gbm.predict(dev_data)
predict_dev_value = np.exp(predict_dev_log)

# Mesh grid for plotting 292 observations
xx = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0, 292, 292)).T
xx = xx.astype(np.float32)

# Plot the predictions
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14,6))
plt.plot(xx, dev_values_log, 'b.', markersize=10, label='Observations')
plt.plot(xx, predict_dev_log, 'r-', label='Predictions', alpha=0.8)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I'd be very appreciative if anyone could help me create a similar plot containing my observations with the gradient booted regression line plotted!

[My attempt gradient boosted regression plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lveAJ.png)

Comment: So what is wrong with your plot? Do you get an error or is something plotted wrong? Its hard to help since we don't have your data and can't even see the plot that you made.

Comment: I've now edited my question so the resulting plot is displayed.  Forgive the oversight!